# System almost freezes when memory full

Tags: kernel, swap

I have tested with zram or physical swap on SSD. When memory usage is very high, for example a memory leak, the system starts to swap.

At this moment, `top` shows 10% IO wait, 20% CPU per kswapd. But SSD IO is very high, even there is no physical swap. And system is lagging very much.

This only occurs when memory is almost full. And I never observed this in previous Ubuntu version, until I updated to Bionic a year ago, fresh installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem, and I would recommend you to put swappiness at 10.
What is your current swappiness value?

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

The default is 60, while recommended is 10. There are a lot of guides as well. To change it:

```
sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Add a line at the end:

```
vm.swappiness=10
```

Will this solve it completely? NO!
This will only swap lesser. But you need to have some free memory when your system goes full, and for that, the following should do the job (in the same file, /etc/sysctl.conf, after setting vm.swappiness):

```
vm.min_free_kbytes=65536
```

Reboot for the effect. Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Edit: I recommend keeping 500MB free if you have a lot of RAM.

Comment: Thanks. I may need some time to verify the change to see if it helps.

Comment: Did it make any difference for you?

Comment: I think the answer is YES. I have got any trouble yet.